# Warning: ftp_login(): User cannot log in, home directory inaccessible

Tags: php

I am trying to connect and retrieve file from server, but I got the following error:

> Warning: `ftp_login()`: User cannot log in, home directory inaccessible.

```
define('FTP_HOST', 'example.com');
define('FTP_USER', 'xxxx');
define('FTP_PASS', 'xxxx');
$conn_id = ftp_connect(FTP_HOST) or die("Couldn't connect"); 
echo var_dump($conn_id);
$c = ftp_login($conn_id, FTP_USER, FTP_PASS);
echo "<br>";
echo var_dump($c);
```

Comment: So can you login with the same credential using "normal" FTP client?

Comment: Yes I can login using normal FTP client.

Comment: I think there may be an issue with the directory have you tried passing directory as argument in ftp_connect() something like this `ftp_connect('ftp://example.com/path1/path2/')`

Comment: you have warning in ftp_login() which means that you are connected you just haven't got right permissions to this directory which may mean that you are accessing wrong directory

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it also matters if you use passive or active mode for connecting.
I recently bumped into that with a similar problem as you are having.

You could try this before the logging in:

```
// turn passive mode on
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
```

Answer (score -1):

In most cases, this error occurs only when FTP authorization rules for default FTP site are not set.

Comment: Any solutions for this